# Retrieve Column header depending on values present in an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets ( sheet 1 and sheet 2) . Sheet 1 has 500X500 table. I want to 
- Loop through each row ( each cell )
- Identify the cells which have a value ' X' in it
- Pick the respective column header value and store it in a cell in worksheet 2

For example

```
AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  FF  GG  HH
GHS                     X   
FSJ         X               
FSA X                       
MSD                         
SKD                         
SFJ X                       X
SFJ                         
SFM             X           
MSF                     X
```

Is there a way of writing a macro which will pull values in the form of

```
GHS -> GG
FSJ->DD
.
.
SFJ->BB HH
```

I have tried looping algorithms but does not seem to work. Could anyone please help me as I am very new to macros.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Assumed that GHS, FSJ ... in column A

```
Sub ColnItem()
Dim x, y, z As Integer
Dim sItem, sCol As String
Dim r As Range

z = 1
For y = 1 To 500
  sItem = Cells(y, 1)
  sCol = ""
  For x = 2 To 500
    If UCase(Cells(y, x)) = "X" Then
      If Len(sCol) > 0 Then sCol = sCol & " "
      sCol = sCol & ColumnName(x)
    End If
  Next
  If Len(sCol) > 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(z, 1) = sItem & " -> " & sCol
    z = z + 1
  End If
Next
End Sub

Function ColumnName(ByVal nCol As Single) As String
Dim sC As String
Dim nC, nRest, nDivRes As Integer

sC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nC = Len(sC)

nRest = nCol Mod nC
nDivRes = (nCol - nRest) / nC

If nDivRes > 0 Then ColumnName = Mid(sC, nDivRes, 1)
ColumnName = ColumnName & Mid(sC, nRest, 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have placed the values GG, etc., in separate columns of Sheet2, but the code could be modified to put all the information (for a row) in a single cell.

```
Sub GetColumnHeadings()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng As Range
    Dim off As Integer

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'CurrentRegion is the Range highlighted when we press Ctrl-A from A1
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In rng1
        If rng.Column = 1 Then off = 0
        If rng.Value = "X" Then
            rng2.Value = rng.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
            off = off + 1
            rng2.Offset(0, off).Value = rng.EntireColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value
        End If
        'if we are looking at the last column of the Sheet1 data, and
        'we have put something into the current row of Sheet2, move to 
        'the next row down (in Sheet2)
        If rng.Column = rng1.Column And rng2.Value <> "" Then
            Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng2 = Nothing
    Set rng1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've also based in on the spreadsheet sample from the original post, where AA appears to be in cell A1.